# Visit visa refused appendix v 4.5 a and c

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds, moroccan-citizens

I applied for my friend to visit me here in the uk.
I am fully sponsoring his visit here.
We admit we made a stupid mistake and we thought that his "bank statements" were not worth submitting.
As you can see, he doesnt make alot of money and he is a full time student, working only part time.
His employer stated in his application that he gets paid cash in hand.
In his employment position they dont give "payslips".

Upon the question of " how much are you going to spend personally on this trip" we wrote 200gbp.
At the end of he application i stated that this was actually going to be paid by me (the sponsor)
as i am fully funding his trip.

All other documents we have, we would like to apply again if we are able to put his cash in hand cash into his bank account each month (so they can see) will this help when we reapply?

it might be difficult to obtain pay slips as in his country they don't actually use these in the type of job he does....... ??
below is a copy of refusal letter.
any help will be much appreciated.

The decision
I have refused your application for a visit visa because I am not satisfied that you meet the requirements of paragraph(s) 4.2 of Appendix V because
 You state in your application that you wish to visit the UK for 14 days to visit your friend and for tourism purposes. You state that you are an employed student in Morocco with a monthly income of MAD 800 (£65 @£1=MAD12.2578) and monthly outgoings of MAD 600 (£49). You also state that this trip will cost MAD 2500 (£203) to you personally. I acknowledge that you state you will receive financial support from your friend in the UK. While I am satisfied your friend in the UK is able to provide this support, I am not satisfied having considered all the information you have provided that you meet the other requirements set out in Appendix V of the Immigration Rules.

 I note that you have submitted numerous documents demonstrating the financial circumstances of your friend in the UK. However, the information provided does not demonstrate your own current financial circumstances, your receipt of your stated monthly income or how you yourself are supported on a day to day basis in Morocco. Furthermore, the information provided does not demonstrate any additional funds in your name from which you will support yourself for the duration of your stay in the UK. As such, I am not satisfied that the information provided gives an accurate portrayal of your current personal and financial circumstances nor satisfied that your intentions to visit the UK are as stated and that you will leave at the end of your visit.
 In light of all the above I am not satisfied that you will leave the UK at the end of your visit and are genuinely seeking entry for a purpose that is permitted by the visitor routes. Appendix V4.2 (a) and (c).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e) (and links therein.)

Comment: @abbie Paying cash in hand income into his bank account without documentation to prove the source of the money is legal is futile. Plus a visit of 14 days makes little sense right now or in the near future given the ever-changing quarantine requirements.

Comment: He of course can get payslips from his employer, but as i said from the country he is from its not usually given. Would he be able to deposit the funds himself if he has the employment contract and the payslips ? ..... the intention of the visit was not really for tourism. It was to visit me here as it as been one hell of a year for us all, especially here in lockdown. We did actually apply before these more strict measures.